# Rubyists: What is this called?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a pool of enumerables that I want to group by an attribute:

```
cars = Car.all.group_by(&:color)
```

Then I want to iterate over those `cars` like so:

```
cars.inject([]) do |stack, (color, cars)|
  stack << cars.each do |car|
   ...
  end
end
```

What is the term for the block variable extension (between the parentheses)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call it *destructuring bind* or *destructuring assignment*, that's what it's usually called in other programming languages. In Ruby, it's often called *multiple assignment* or *parallel assignment*. If you want to know what it's "officially" called, you could look it up in the [Draft ISO Specification](http://Ruby-Std.Netlab.Jp/).

Comment: Nice. So it's a block variable parallel assignment. I have people ask about it during code reviews; it's nice to have a term handy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weak form of pattern matching, one of the defining features of certain functional languages (ML, Haskell, and their ilk). In Python it's typically called unpacking. I don't know if Ruby has a particular term for it.